# Keep getting this ERROR " AF_INET address must be tuple, not socket". Don't know how to solve it and what does it mean

Tags: python, server, pycharm, httprequest, http-get

I am a little new to Python.
Using the latest version of Python 3.7.3
I'm trying to build a server that listens to HTTP GET requests at localhost/8080.

The code is pretty simple:

```
PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.HTTPServer

global httpd
httpd =http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I keep getting the same error no matter what I do:
"TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not socket"

When I run the code it start serving. I know that because it prints to the console "serving at port 8080"
but when I sent a GET request, I get the error.

I am sending a simple GET request from Postman like so:
"http://localhost:8080"

HOW CAN I FIX THIS?
WHERE IS THE Problem?

Comment: `handler` should be a subclass of [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), not another server.

Comment: very helpful.
thank u